# Zurb Foundation 6 Large node_modules folder size

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, node-modules

I apologize if this is a terrible question, or I'm just missing something... but I just can't figure out the reason for this...

So I've been using foundation for years now, and just started with F6. After a couple site designs, I noticed that my cloud services (GDrive and Dropbox where I store my repos) were crashing like crazy.

So I used one of my file scanning apps to see what was happening, and for some reason, ALL my sites now that are built using the manual zurb install via terminal instructions (from the online docs) are around 1GB per-site! - and there were SO MANY files being created in the back end inside the node_modules folder, I'm not sure what to do.

Is this normal? If so, there's no way I can continue to use F6 if each site I build is going to have 1GB+ of random compiler files. Please help!! Maybe I'm just doing something wrong? All my sites pre-F6 combined (the top right corner of the image) over YEARS and dozens of sites don't compate to just one F6 site I'm working on.

[huge file sizes in node modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilwhm.png)